# How to animate a sprite in spriral movement

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I want to move a SKSpritenode from one position to another on screen with a path to follow like the below image. [image: path to follow]

What i am currently doing is -

```
    var circle          =   UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(self.position.x, self.position.y, self.parentScene.frame.size.width*0.20, self.parentScene.frame.size.width*0.20), cornerRadius: self.parentScene.frame.size.width*0.20)
   let followCircle    =   SKAction.followPath(circle.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 6.0)
   let moveAction      =   SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: self.parentScene.frame.size.width*0.15,dy: 0), duration: 3);
   let repeatAction    =   SKAction.sequence([followCircle,moveAction])
   let finalAction     =   SKAction.repeatActionForever(repeatAction)
   self.runAction(finalAction)
```

But i am not getting the desired result. sprite follow the circular path and move in horizontal direction after that but insteade of keep following the path it just start againg from where it was started initially.

Please help..!!!

Comment: Basically, this type of movements are done by using the mathematical equations of your desire shape like spiral , so once you implement the equation, you get the x and y coordinate of sprite from that equation.

Comment: Can you please provide me some example for such mathematical equations.

Comment: http://blog.donkim.org/post/11850806340/getting-a-spiral-uibezierpath-in-objective-c